# React redirect to login if not authenticated - Spring security

Tags: reactjs, redirect, spring-security, axios

I have a Java/Jsf web app containing a Rest API with Spring Security session based authentication.

I’m currently building a React small app for using this API, and would like to redirect the user to the login (jsf) page when not logged in.

So far I'm just getting the login page returned as data.
Not sure if this has to be fixed in Spring or React side, and how to do it.

Thanks

```
getSchedulesByFarmAndDate(farmId, startDate, endDate) {
    return axios.get(
      authService.getApiUrl() +
      `/reports/schedules/filterByFarmAndDate?id=${farmId}`, { withCredentials: true }
    );
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I had is that my Java application has already a login page (JSF), so there is no way to know in React if the user is logged in unless I call the API.
I figured out a way to return a 401 from Spring by doing this in the Spring security config:

```
http.exceptionHandling().defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
   getRestAuthenticationEntryPoint(),
   new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**")
);

private AuthenticationEntryPoint getRestAuthenticationEntryPoint({
    return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

This way, if API returns a 401 code to React, I'll redirect to the Login page. Not the cleanest way to do this but works as starting point.